# conexion odbc php

Tags: php, odbc

Gracias por su ayuda colegas, apenas comienzo en el mundo de la programacion agradezco mucho su ayuda. estoy haciendo un menu de busqueda con php con conexion odbc. el archivo de conexion es el siguiente:

---

```
<? 
$dsn = "PG_EXCEL"; 
$usuario="postgres";
$clave="telguasa+1";

$cid=odbc_connect($dsn, $usuario, $clave);

if (!$cid){
    exit("<strong>Ya ocurrido un error tratando de conectarse con el origen de datos.</strong>");
}
```

---

el menu de busqueda es el siguiente pero resulta que no puedo visualizar los archivos segun la fecha que se consulta el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$desde = $_POST['desde'];
$hasta = $_POST['hasta'];

//COMPROBAMOS QUE LAS FECHAS EXISTAN
if(isset($desde)==false){
    $desde = $hasta;
}

if(isset($hasta)==false){
    $hasta = $desde;
}

//EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA DE BUSQUEDA

$registro = "SELECT * FROM tarificado.rep_con WHERE fecha_dcms BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta'";


//CREAMOS NUESTRA VISTA Y LA DEVOLVEMOS AL AJAX

echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th width="200">central</th>
                <th width="150">centrales_nombre</th>
                <th width="150">fecha_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">archivo_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">correlativo_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">bytes_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">archivo_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">correlativo_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">fecha_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">bytes_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">ivr_num_eventos</th>
                <th width="150">dif_bytes</th>      
            </tr>';
if(($registro)>0)
{
    while($registro2 = odbc_fetch_array($registro)){ 
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$registro2['Central'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['centrales_nombre'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['fecha_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['archivo_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['correlativo_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['bytes_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['archivo_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['correlativo_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['fecha_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['bytes_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['ivr_num_eventos'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['dif_bytes'].'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<tr>
                <td colspan="6">No se encontraron resultados</td>
            </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

que estare haciendo mal? agradezco mucho sus comentarios.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
if(($registro)>0)
```

La variable $registro es un string, y un string evaluado como integer retorna 0 en PHP.  Creo que te falta una instruccion para correr el query que tienes guardado en esa variable.

Algo asi como:

```
$registro = odbc_exec($cid, $registro);
```

Comment: De acuerdo gracias y que instruccion seria la que me hace falta? de antemano gracias.

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias AlanFCM sos un capo. me sirvio mucho tu ayuda. ya funciona un saludo.

Comment: @abnermolina Si te funciono, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta